# Polynomial representation with shared root

Tags: linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

Let $R$ be a polynomial quotient ring of the form $F_3[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]/\langle \{x_i^3-x_i\}_{1\le i\le n} \rangle$ and $\{f_i\}_{1\le i \le m}$ be elements of $R$, where $m > n$. We know that the family of polynomials share a common root $(r_1,...,r_n)$.

I guess it means that an ideal generated by $\{ f_i\}$ is identical to an ideal generated by $\{ x_i -r_i\}$.

Now here is the question:

1. Any $x_i-r_i$ can be represented by the $F_3$-linear summation of monomials of the form $\prod_{i=1}^m f_i^{b_i}$, where $b_i \in \{0,1,2\}$ over $R$?
2. Another polynomial $f_0$ shares the same root as well. In this case, the $f_0$ can be represented by the $F_3$-linear summation of monomials of the form $\prod_{i=1}^m f_i^{b_i}$, where $b_i \in \{0,1,2\}$ over $R$?

Thank you a lot.

Note: $F_3$ is a prime field of order 3.

Comment: Did you check the case $n = 1$? What if $r_1 = 0, f_1 = 0$ and $f_2 = x_1^2$?

Comment: That's a good point. But I except for the case $f_i=0$. More precisely, I'm interested in the case that $\langle f_i \rangle = \langle x_i -r_i \rangle$ is guaranteed.